# how to patch the wall with multiple layers of paints?

Tags: paint, hole, patch

I'm patching a hole in a bedroom. There are multiple layers of paints. I use lightweight spackle. Can anyone tell me how to fix the uneven wall? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: You are on the right path. Plaster, sanding, repeat ...

Comment: Thanks. Do I do the same for covering the ripped-off paint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure any loose or chipping paint is removed.
Second, for an area that large, I would use joint compound instead of spackle. Also, a wide taping knife will help.

One more tip: For a relatively small area such as this in an existing house, in order not to get so much dust in your house, I recommend the following:

1. Be careful not to apply too much joint compound. Use your knife to eliminate ridges when you apply it.
2. After the joint compound dries, use the damp sponge "sanding" method to smooth what imperfections remain. After this, actual sanding may not even be necessary.

Comment: For one time repairs you can buy plastic mud knives cheap. A 12" knife would be good for a spot that large.

Comment: Get yourself a drywall sanding block for sanding, they're approximately 3" x 9". That will help you get a flat, even, repair.